# How to start new activity when recieve new sms (I used Intent but is show error)?

Tags: android

How do i start new activity if particular sms receive and its have particular value? i used intent but is show error in code this error is show in intent

> The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type SmsReceiver

below is my code:

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.util.Map;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";     
            if(str.contains("00"));
            {
                Intent k = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),    
   AgAppMenu.class);
                startActivity(k);
            }

        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   

}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start `Activity` as a new task.

```
Intent k = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AgAppMenu.class);
k.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(k);
```

Comment: is show error again      The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type SmsReceiver

Comment: add `context.startActivity(k);`

Comment: Nota: the Flag part is ver important, too, as it is the only way to start an activity from outside an activity.